# Добавить id деда в таблицу внука

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблицы

```
base
1. base_id 

data
1. tr_id     
2. base_id   - соответствует base_id таблицы "base"

field
1. field_id 
2. tr_id    - соответствует tr_id таблицы "data"
```

Нужно в таблице field создать поле base_id и правильно заполнить его в уже существующих записях.
То есть таблица уже заполнена, но в таблицы field не было поля base_id, а сейчас его надо добавить туда.
Таблица field привязана к data, а data к base.
То есть как бы base - это дед, data отец, field внук. И у внука нет ссылки на деда, а есть только на отца.

Comment: Это поле добавлять не надо. Оно вносит избыточность и неоднозначность в данные. И нарушает вторую нормальную форму https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: А как выполнять поиск?
Скажем нужно выполнить поиск в записях где 
base_id=5 AND data='строка'
в таблице field

Comment: Это нужно найти все tr_id в таблице data и затем 
искать во всех tr_id в таблице field

Comment: Сначала пишите запрос, который получает ID деда на основе ID отца (буквально `select base_id from X where tr_id=Y`), а потом пишите обычный update для третьей таблицы, где к SET полю приравниваете подзапрос в виде этого самого select, в котором вместо Y ссылаетесь на нужный id из меняемой таблицы. Или используете синтаксис update с join https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html

Comment: А это не повлияет на производительность если в таблице будет несколько миллионов записей? Для каждого base может быть от 5 до 200 data и для каждого дата может быть от 1 до 40 field.

Comment: Повлияет. Но все надо пробовать на реальных данных. Общий подход такой - сначала делаем в нормальной форме (как сейчас) и пробуем. если при правильно построенных индексах производительности не хватает, то тогда вносим избыточность в данные.